# Format font size Etc in a cell

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am currently running this code but it won't work.

```
ObjTable.Cell(3,2).Range.Text = "hello"
objTable.Cell(3,2).range
     .Font.Name = "Arial"
     .Font.Size = "14"
```

Only the words come out but not the format of the words.

Answer (score 1):

You need to encapsulate the `.Font.Name` and `.Font.Size` in a with statement like so:

```
ObjTable.Cell(3,2).Range.Text = "hello"

With objTable.Cell(3,2).Range
     .Font.Name = "Arial"
     .Font.Size = "14"
End With
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/with-statement for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Even more efficient:

```
With objTable.Cell(3,2).Range
  .Text = "hello"
  .Font.Name = "Arial"
  .Font.Size = "14"
End With
```